# how to access json field with "-" e.g. 'data-id': 'smth'

Tags: javascript, json

I need some help, so I need to access the field in json, I got the json from an API, I know how to access a json but there's one problem, I can't access the field with apostrophe

here's the json I received:

```
datas: {
  stats: {
    attack: 60
    defense: 70
    'special-defense': 50
    speed: 90
  }
}
```

I want to access the special-defense, I have tried `datas.stats.special-defense` but isn't working,
I tried `datas.stats.'special-defense'` too and it's giving invalid syntax.
I can access another field like `speed`,`attack`, and `defense` with `datas.stats.speed` etc.

is there any way to access that field?

Comment: `datas.stats['special-defense']`

Comment: Use bracket notation.

Comment: I never think that, but thanks a lot